# Añadir paginación a una tabla sin afectar al buscador

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

tengo una tabla que carga valores de la base de datos.

Es esta:

```
            <table class='table' id="tabla">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Edad</th><th>Direccion</th><th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span></th>
            </tr>           
   <?php
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bdpersona");     
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
            exit();
        }
        $consulta= "SELECT * FROM tbcontactos";
        if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) 
        {
            while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_row()) 
            {                   
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$fila[0]</td><td>$fila[1]</td><td>$fila[2]</td><td>$fila[3]</td>";    
                echo"<td>";                     
                echo "<a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editUsu' data-id='" .$fila[0] ."' data-nombre='" .$fila[1] ."' data-edad='" .$fila[2] ."' data-direccion='" .$fila[3] ."' class='btn btn-warning'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>Editar</a> ";          
                echo "<a class='btn btn-danger' href='elimina.php?id=" .$fila[0] ."'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>Eliminar</a>";     
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            $resultado->close();
        }
        $mysqli->close();           

     ?>
        </table>
```

Hasta aquí todo bien. Además, justo encima he puesto un buscador que funciona perfectamente. Funciona con este script

```
    <script language="javascript">
    function doSearch()
    {
        var tableReg = document.getElementById('tabla');
        var searchText = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value.toLowerCase();
        var cellsOfRow="";
        var found=false;
        var compareWith="";

        // Recorremos todas las filas con contenido de la tabla
        for (var i = 1; i < tableReg.rows.length; i++)
        {
            cellsOfRow = tableReg.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
            found = false;
            // Recorremos todas las celdas
            for (var j = 0; j < cellsOfRow.length && !found; j++)
            {
                compareWith = cellsOfRow[j].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
                // Buscamos el texto en el contenido de la celda
                if (searchText.length == 0 || (compareWith.indexOf(searchText) > -1))
                {
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if(found)
            {
                tableReg.rows[i].style.display = '';
            } else {
                // si no ha encontrado ninguna coincidencia, esconde la
                // fila de la tabla
                tableReg.rows[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Hasta aquí no tengo ningún problema.
Pero, a vistas a mejorar siempre, he visto que cuando tengo más de 8 elementos, se hace molesto, por lo que he pensado, necesito una paginación para la tabla por si llego a tener muchos usuarios y que se haga más cómodo y visual.

Se que lo mejor de todo hubiera sido hacer mi CRUD con datatable, que me hubiera ahorrado todo ello, pero después de un mes trabajado en este CRUD me gustaría acabarlo y no puedo dedicarle más tiempo(A no se de que mi tabla se pudiese pasar a datatable sin trastocar mucho el codigo).

Por lo que mi pregunta es, ¿Como puedo ponerle paginación a mi tabla, por ejemplo de ver 5 elementos en cada página? ¿Afectaría poner paginación a mi buscador?

Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: ¿Que herramienta  pensabas usar para hacer la paginaciòn?  Te recomendaría usa https://datatables.net/

Comment: leiste mi texto? jejeje. Se puede ajustar mi tabla a una datatable?

Comment: Prueba con el ejemplo de la pagina y me dices que tal te va. Al final lo que  hace es convertir tus columnas  ya llenadas al modelo de la tabla.

Comment: vale, intentaré hacerlo. Pero el código de relleno de filas se ve afectado?

Comment: No, solo ejecuta  la función $(idtabla).DataTable() después que llenes la tabla

Comment: estoy teniendo bastante problemas... se me descoloca todo y no carga bien

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74780/discussion-between-bercklyn-carlosviza-and-vidal).